# Can't run swifter

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to download swifter from the following site:

https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter

I opened the project file in Xcode but after clicking the run button, it doesn't load the iOS Simulator as usual but simply displays the "Build succeeded" message.

Tried playing around with the project settings and all that and even setting the navigation controller to be the initial view controller. Still can't get the iOS simulator to start and run the project.

Not sure what is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to build the Swifter framework.  The framework target is not an app, so building the project will just build the framework.

[image: framework]

To build the sample app, change the target to the "SwifterDemoiOS" target.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Do like:

[image]

Choose from the list what you want, iOS or Mac version and just later run it.